# Fedora LiveUSB Creator not showing target device

Tags: fedora, fedora-15, fedora-17, fedora-13, fedora-14

I downloaded LiveUSB and it doesn't show a target device and i cant find one.  I don't know what to do so if someone can held that would be great.

Comment: Have you tried plugging in different USB sticks to see if they are recognised by your computer ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've checked to see if the target device is showing up on the computer from which you're doing this. If its a windows machine, you can try [this](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/wiki/FAQ#MyUSBdriveisnotshowingupintheRemovableDeviceslist).